# Combine 2 columns data in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns, rows

I have a problem combining 2 columns in 1 pandas Dataframe.

My Dataframe data is like:

| Nombre | Valor | Fecha |
| --- | --- | --- |
| totalVehiculos | 2132.00 | 2021-09-19 01:12:52 |
| totalVelocidad | 81.98 | 2021-09-19 01:12:52 |
| totalVehiculos | 1501.00 | 2021-09-19 02:07:51 |
| totalVelocidad | 84.66 | 2021-09-19 02:07:51 |
| totalVehiculos | 1250.00 | 2021-09-19 03:02:48 |
| totalVelocidad | 86.10 | 2021-09-19 03:02:48 |

And I would like to know if it's possible to be:

| totalVehiculos | totalVelocidad | Fecha |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2132.00 | 81.98 | 2021-09-19 01:12:52 |
| 1501.00 | 84.66 | 2021-09-19 02:07:51 |
| 1250.00 | 86.10 | 2021-09-19 03:02:48 |

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot or https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html

Comment: `df.pivot(index='Fecha', columns='Nombre', values='Valor')`